# Border radius on text area with java fx scene builder

Tags: html, css, javafx, scene

I wanted to set border radius to a text area and i've done this giving border and background radius at all the elements that compose the text area.The problem is that:when the text area is active the top-left border doesn't color itself of blue.Why?

Comment: Can you add your code please? HTML & CSS, in a fiddle would be best.

Comment: @PaulRedmond he is using javafx it does not work in fiddle :-) , the CSS styling is a little different in javafx. it will still be helpful if he post his code :-)

Comment: Hi thanks for your answers:):)What code can I post to permit you to understand my problem over my code?The code of caspian.css or modena.css?

Comment: You should  always  provide an [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), this includes in your case the code where you created the text area, set the style and so on.